# Have the last row in a column expand to the remainder of the viewport?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create (using Bootstrap 5) a website with 2 columns above a certain breakpoint where the last row in each column fills the remainder of the viewport space available - the page shouldn't scroll. Below the set breakpoint each row should just consume the amount of space its content requires - the page can scroll if needed.

Between each cell there should also be an even gutter space.

[image: Visual of intended layout]

Hopefully the 3 examples make sense - laptop (2 columns), big mobile and small mobile (1 column):

- The thick black border represents the screen viewport.
- The thin black border represents each cell.
- Blue is the guttering.
- Green is each cell's padding.
- Each cell is numbered 1 to 5.

If it helps, the ultimate goal here is to create a 'bento box' single page website like https://bentobox.framer.website/light-mode.

It seems to work mainly (minus the guttering) when viewed above the 'md' breakpoint. When narrowing the page below the 'md' breakpoint however I'm left with strange gaps following cells 3 and 5.

It seems like I need the correct combination of height utilities, such as 'h-100' or 'vh-100', as well as elements of Flexbox from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - code fixes, different approaches, etc.

Many thanks!

```html
<html data-bs-theme="light" lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>
</head>

<body class="bg-body">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row vh-100">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="bg-body-secondary p-4 rounded-4">
              1
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="bg-body-secondary p-4 rounded-4">
              2
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row flex-md-grow-1">
            <div class="bg-body-secondary p-4 rounded-4">
              3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="bg-body-secondary p-4 rounded-4">
              4
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row flex-md-grow-1">
            <div class="bg-body-secondary p-4 rounded-4">
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```